# How to combine multiple rows in datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a json data that I am trying to dynamically apeend to jquery datatables

**My json data looks something like this:**

```
  details = [{info:'sdsd',sub:'dsdsd',otherinfo:'dsds'},{info:'gfdd',sub:'zzzzz',otherinfo:null},
 {info:'1212',sub:'34343',otherinfo:'dsdaw2'}]
```

**I am appending to my datatable by doing:**

```
for(let i =0;i<details.length;i++){
      tableSummary.row.add($(`<tr><td>${details[i].info}</td><td>${details[i].sub}</td></tr>`)).draw()

     if(details[i].otherinfo){
           tableSummary.row.add($(`<tr><td>OTHER INFO</td><td>${details[i].otherinfo}</td><td></td></tr>`)).draw()
          }
}
```

As you can see in my JSON data `otherinfo` can sometimes be null. I want the row showing the info and the row showing the other info on 2 different rows. However, I want them to be treated as a single entity. The table should only allow sorting based on the info row and searching something should bring up both rows instead of just one.

Basically I want to combine 2 rows and always have them combined no matter how the table is sorted. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try Datatable child row option

Something like this

```
var jsonData = [{"info":"sdsd","sub":"dsdsd","otherinfo":"dsds"},{"info":"gfdd","sub":"zzzzz","otherinfo":null},
 {"info":"1212","sub":"34343","otherinfo":"dsdaw2"}];

function format ( d ) {
    var trs='';
    trs+='<tr><td>'+ (d.otherinfo != null ? d.otherinfo : "")+'</td></tr>';

    return '<table class="table table-border table-hover">'+
           '<thead>'+
              '<th>OTHER INFO</th>'+
           '</thead><tbody>' +

           trs+
        '</tbody></table>';
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "data": jsonData,
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "info"},
            { "data": "sub"}
        ]
    });


   $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
          row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc2zrgu1/)